# Change String to Date in Android

Tags: android, date

I have String like "Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM". I want to convert it to Date. I am using SimpleDateFormat. But it is giving me exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'. How to solve it??

```
 Date date ; 
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse(start);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Post the code section to show us what pattern you are using

Comment: when i am changing it like this: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa");
 then i am getting  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Feb 7, 2012 3:10:00 PM"

Comment: Firstly, you may have some misunderstanding on the use of the **DateFormat.parse()**, it is used to parse the String in the pattern specified into type **Date**, i.e. "dd-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss", so the string in the **parse()** should match the pattern. Secondly, if you want to enforce the date in the specific format, you should use **DateFormat.format()** instead, see the document provided below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps it should be small letter 'y' instead of capital one.
FYI, See:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Can anyone please help?? What the format i have to pass in the SimpleDateFormat.